# Python parser for kpl playlist types

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a file like the following:

```
<xml>
    <0 filename="relative path to file 0">
        <tag artist="Artist 0" album="Album 0" title="Title 0" year="Unknown Year" comment="" genre="Other" track="3" gid="12" has_tag="True"/>
    </0>
    <1 filename="relative path to file 1">
        <tag artist="Artist 1" album="Album 1" title="Title 1" year="2004" comment="Comment for this track" genre="Rock" track="12" gid="17" has_tag="True"/>
    </1>
    <2 filename="relative path to file 2">
        <tag artist="Artist 2" album="Album 2" title="Title 2" year="Unknown Year" comment="" genre="" track="9" gid="255" has_tag="True"/>
    </2>
    <3 filename=" relative path to file 3">
        <tag artist="Artist 3" album="Album 3" title="Title 3" year="Unknown Year" comment="" genre="Other" track="7" gid="12" has_tag="True"/>
    </3>
    <4 filename="relative path to file 4">
        <tag artist="Artist 4" album="Album 4" title="Title 4" year="1996" comment="Track 9" genre="Metal" track="9" gid="9" has_tag="True"/>
    </4>
    <info creation_day="2006-08-05" modified_day="2006-08-05" author="" player="player name" player_version="real player version" kpl_version="1"/>
</xml>
```

How can i parse it with python (`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`)?

I try:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(kpl_content))
root = tree.getroot()
```

but it fails

```
$ python "Papinhio_player.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Papinhio_player.py", line 351, in 
    self.main_ui.menu_playlist_import.triggered.connect(lambda: self.open_import
_playlist_file_window())
  File "Papinhio_player.py", line 1918, in open_import_playlist_file_window
    import_playlist_file_run_code = Import_Playlist_File_Code(self,file_full_pat
h,extension)
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\Papinhio player\src\main\python_files/import_playlist_
file_code.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.parse_kpl(content)
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\Papinhio player\src\main\python_files/import_playlist_
file_code.py", line 599, in parse_kpl
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(kpl_content))
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1320, in
 XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, colum
n 2
```

I have made i try to replace the node names 0->t0, 1->t1, 2->t2,..

```
            f = open(self.playlist_filename, "r", encoding="utf8")
            lines = f.readlines()
            final_file = ""
            for line in lines:
                current_char = 0
                total_char = len(line)
                while(current_char1 and line[current_char+1]=="/":
                        final_file +="/"
                        node_number = "t"
                        for char_2 in line[current_char+2:]:
                            try:
                                char_2 = int(char_2)
                                node_number += str(char_2)
                            except:
                                if(node_number=="t"):
                                    current_char +=2
                                    break
                                else:
                                    final_file +=node_number
                                    current_char += len(node_number)+1
                                    break
                        
                    else:
                        current_char+=1
            print(final_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, colum n 2`

is caused by

```
<0 filename="relative path to file 0">
```

as `0` is not compliant with XML specification's [Common Syntactic Constructs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210.html#sec-common-syn) which says that

> A **Name** is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation
> characters, and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores,
> colons, or full stops, together known as name characters.

Therefore digit inside or at end of name is okay, but name starting with digit is not.

You might try to make it compliant using `re.sub` as follows

```
import re
kpl_content = re.sub(r'(</?)(\d+)', r'\1t\2', kpl_content)
```

but if it would work as intended depend on your input data.

Comment: So how can i use a regexp to rewrite the node tags? (For example t0,t1,t2,t3,...)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Check mine in the updated question. Yours it's much more cleaner and easy to use.